# Isntance of PDO given instead of namespace name - PSR4 Autoloading with composer

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, composer-php, psr-4

I am trying to learn how to use PDO. I have a very small application that uses namespaces. I use composer to autoload the classes.

I am trying to follow [PHPTheRightWay](http://www.phptherightway.com/#pdo_extension) MVC approach to PDO but I am failing. I have setup my DbModel class to match their one and in my php code I create a new instance of it and parse the PDO object.

Class:

```
namespace Acme;

class DbModel {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct(PDO $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function getAllPlayers()
    {
        return $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM player');
    }
}
```

Page:

```
use Acme\DbModel;
use Acme\Player;
use Acme\Team;
use Acme\Match;

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=football', 'root', '');
$model = new DbModel($db);
```

However, I get the following error. I have no idea why this is happening.

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Acme\DbModel::__construct() must be an instance of Acme\PDO, instance of PDO given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\footballMatch\matchDay.php on line 9 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\footballMatch\src\DbModel.php on line 9

After adding this class I run `composer install` and `composer dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the root namespace prefix to PDO wherever it's used, e.g.:

```
public function __construct(\PDO $db)
```

For now, your script assumes that the class named PDO should be under the Acme namespace, which isn't the case.

Comment: Alternatively, add `use PDO;` after the namespace line. This will import classes names into the current namespace and makes `Acme\PDO` valid - pointing to `\PDO` because of the `use`.